# Teiid Spring Boot: @SelectQuery supports of where clause parameters

Tags: spring-boot, teiid

From my understanding, `@SelectQuery` will return all data of columns defined. What if I would like to restrict data return from the query by adding where clause with parameterized filter?

For example, the following SQL query support filter by ssn:

```
SELECT id, name, ssn FROM mydb.customer 
WHERE ssn in :ssn
```

`:ssn` is valid list of SSNs.

In short, is Teiid Spring Boot support parameterized view?

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: what if you do WHERE mydb.ssn in :ssn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At entity definition level you can not parameterize the where clause like ":ssn", if you want can supply a static value or referenced value like a = b is fine.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Unluckily, the value is dynamic (cannot be static), any alternative way to restrict the data return from entity instead of all data?

Comment: If it is dynamic it needs to be in the user query.